# Pagination with lazy loading for arbitrary content

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I have been working with jpaginate to get an pagination effect for a lot of data. It works fine but all the content is loading at one time. Is there a jQuery plugin for pagination which loads the content only for the current page ?

Answer (score 0):

For tabular data you can make use of [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html).